# Charting with WPF VS 2010 (.NET 4)

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, charts

I need to add chart to my WPF application and I can't understand do I need to install the WPF toolkit if i work with .net 4?
On one hand I read everywhere that the toolkit is already integrated in .net 4, on the other hand I can't find system.windows.controls.datavisualization.toolkit where I'm trying to add it as a reference

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of controls that haven't been integrated (and might never).

There are also a number of controls that ought to have been there several releases ago.  Numeric up/down is on the top of that list for me.

Comment: so to put it in simpler words in order to use chart i need to install WPF toolkit even if i use .net 4?

Comment: Yes - to use that chart, you will need to install the toolkit.